# Evaluating $\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^4} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^4} \ dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** convert to partial fraction and use [$Si$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral) and $Ci$ integrals.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your hint! (+1)

Comment: Chris: You are welcome.